# Which languages are used for Spell Scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, languages

My guess would be Draconic, and for specific spells: Infernal, Celestial and/or Primordial. Is there an official list of which languages are often found on Spell Scrolls in 5e?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spell scrolls are not written in a given language:

> A spell scroll bears the words of a single spell, **written in a
>   mystical cipher**. If the spell is on your class's spell list you can
>   use an action to read the scroll [..] Otherwise, the scroll is
>   unintelligible. (DMG 200, emphasis mine)

The DM can decide that it uses the runes of or resembles a language if he wants to add flavor or provide a clue, but knowing the language will not help in reading the scroll.

Comment: Great point about "knowing the language will not help". This applies to some esoteric documents in our own world - knowing Hebrew and Aramaic in and of themselves won't really help you a lot in understanding Kaballah.